# List plugins with plugman

Tags: plugins, plugman

I'm reviewing plugman, but it seems it is quite completed to use and I can't figure out how I'm I supposed to know which plugins are installed. How can I know which plugins are installed? How do I version this?

Answer (score 1):

Good question. Since `config.xml` holds only cross platform installations using `cordova plugin` command, any plugins installed using `plugman` is not listed there. I couldn't find a command to list the installed plugins in plugman documentation. I usually look at the plugins folders directly inside the platform directory. For example, if I want to see plugins in Android, I go to:

```
project/platforms/android/cordova/plugins/
```

Here I can see the plugins installed from plugman.